# Excel Workbook fields

Tags: excel-2010

I have an excel workbook that has a field name team leader it has each person listed as true for team leader and false if not a team leader.  I need to know how to make the false become blank and the true to be Team Leader

Answer (score 1):

Use a filter to show only trues, replace the first with "Team Leader", and pull down the bottom right corner of the cell to change all fields. Do something similar for the falses, just clearing contents on all of them.

I would suggest using the connected [Superuser website](https://superuser.com/) in the future for similar issues. It is set up to answer computer and power related questions in general, whereas this site is specifically for coding and development.